# Timeline for SharePoint 2010 Workflows Engine Retirement?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

[Microsoft Announced](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-2010-workflow-retirement-1ca3fff8-9985-410a-85aa-8120f626965f) Workflow 2010 retirement in November 2020.

**Update**
[Posted a user voice suggestion to pospone the retirement date](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/40856713-postope-designer-2010-workflow-engine-retirement). Please vote if you are or your clients are in the same boat with us.

**Our question is**: do you have any documented evidence that MS gave us a clear timeline for Workflow 2010 engine retirement in SharePoint Online?

I am invovled in a large SharePoint-2010-to-SharePoint-Online migration project. We literary have thouthands workflows that are actively used.

Rewriting all of these workflows to SP 2013 engine is not an option. Using Power Automate is not an option either since it's not allowed at our Client's organization.

Any comments and links to the previous MS announcements will be very appreciated!

Comment: I am curious if this includes nintex workflows as well?

Comment: Nintex Workflows are safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This announcement was the first announcement about the retiring of SharePoint 2010 workflows.

If you/your client has a TAM, I would escalate with your objections. Otherwise, search or create a new entry on sharepoint.uservoice.com.

Comment: thank you. Yes, we are escalating with the speed of light. We will push back and object. For now, I am trying to find some of evidence that MS gave the clients a proper warning.

Comment: the fact that the blog post comments thread was lock for no further comment was a strange move from Microsoft, I can't find evidence of any other locked threads and this post had 35k view compared to others with only 3-4k